# how to get right offset of an element? - jQuery

Tags: jquery, offset

This is probably a really simple question, but how do I go about getting the **right** offset of an element in jQuery?

I can do:

```
$("#whatever").offset().left;
```

and it is valid.

But it seems that:

```
$("#whatever").offset().right
```

is undefined.

So how does one accomplish this in jQuery?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Alex, Gary:

As requested, here is my comment posted as an answer:

```
var rt = ($(window).width() - ($whatever.offset().left + $whatever.outerWidth()));
```

Thanks for letting me know.

In pseudo code that can be expressed as:

The right offset is:

The window's [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) MINUS
( The element's [left offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) PLUS the element's [outer width](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) )

Comment: this does not work with CSS transforms, offset will be affected by the transform but outerWidth (and width) will not.

Comment: This is the offset from the right side of the window. For the offset from the left side of the window, see cdZ's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5643921/675721).

Comment: the right-most edge of an element can be found more "natively" `$whatever[0].getBoundingClientRect().right`. this is relative to the window's left edge.

Comment: Thanks brendon. Helpful answer.

Comment: What would this look like in vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 29):

```
var $whatever        = $('#whatever');
var ending_right     = ($(window).width() - ($whatever.offset().left + $whatever.outerWidth()));
```

Reference: [.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

Comment: i think need to add them and then minus 1.  if the width is 2, then left is at 10, and right is not at 12 but 11.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. In CSS, "left" implies "the offset of the leftmost point of the element from the left of the window/parent", and "right" implies "the offset of the rightmost point of the element from the right of the window/parent". So, the correct answer would be: `var rt = ($(window).width() - ($whatever.offset().left + $whatever.outerWidth()));`

Comment: @BrendonCrawford You should move that comment to an answer.

Comment: A note to anyone coming through - the answer above has been edited to correctly reflect the comment made by Brendon.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe I'm  misunderstanding your question, but the offset is supposed to give you two variables: a horizontal and a vertical. This defines the position of the element.  So what you're looking for is:

```
$("#whatever").offset().left
```

and

```
$("#whatever").offset().top
```

If you need to know where the right boundary of your element is, then you should use:

```
$("#whatever").offset().left + $("#whatever").outerWidth()
```

Comment: returns `NaN` (in vanilla js)
`const offsetRight = (ui.offsetLeft + ui.outerWidth)`

Answer (score 9):

Just an addition to what Greg said:

> $("#whatever").offset().left + $("#whatever").outerWidth()

This code will get the right position relative to the left side. If the intention was to get the right side position relative to the right (like when using the CSS `right` property) then an addition to the code is necessary as follows:

> $("#parent_container").innerWidth() - ($("#whatever").offset().left + $("#whatever").outerWidth())

This code is useful in animations where you have to set the right side as a fixed anchor when you can't initially set the `right` property in CSS.

Answer (score 6):

Actually these only work when the window isn't scrolled at all from the top left position.
You have to subtract the window scroll values to get an offset that's useful for repositioning elements so they stay on the page:

```
var offset = $('#whatever').offset();

offset.right = ($(window).width() + $(window).scrollLeft()) - (offset.left + $('#whatever').outerWidth(true));
offset.bottom = ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop()) - (offset.top + $('#whatever').outerHeight(true));
```

Answer (score 5):

Brendon Crawford had the best answer here (in comment), so I'll move it to an answer until he does (and maybe expand a little).

```
var offset = $('#whatever').offset();

offset.right = $(window).width() - (offset.left + $('#whatever').outerWidth(true));
offset.bottom = $(window).height() - (offset.top + $('#whatever').outerHeight(true));
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a native DOM API that achieves this out of the box — [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```
document.querySelector("#whatever").getBoundingClientRect().right
```

Comment: But getBoundingClientRect returns relative to the viewport not relative to the document,which is what offset() provides.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the anchor point of a `div/table (left) = $("#whatever").offset().left;` - ok!

Getting the anchor point of a `div/table (right)` you can use the code below.

```
 $("#whatever").width();
```