# Getting the correct position of div even after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a certain identical `div` on my webpage one below the other .I want to get the correct position of the div to certain message(which is absolutely positioned and fades out later).

so I tried this

```
$('.divs_article').click(function() {
    var left=$(this).offset().left;
    var top=$(this).offset().right;
});
```

but this is giving incorrect results for the `div` that lie below the page,when I scroll down.

Is there any better approach.?

(PS:I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043102/how-to-get-right-offset-of-an-element-jquery).)

Comment: "`the correct position`" related to what? Another element? document.body? viewport?

Comment: What Teemu said. Also, as a general rule for jQuery, have the practice to set `var $this = $(this), $offset = $this.offset();`.

Comment: Relative to the screen,where you view the div

Comment: I.e. related to viewport? If so, [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

A little thought worked for me,

Here the simple trick

```
$("div_article").offset().top-$(document).scrollTop()
```

(PS:I was a dumb question,hope it helps someone in future)

Comment: IIRC, jQuery's `offset` method actually relies on `getBoundingClientRect`, and adds the page's scrolling amounts if no argument is given.