# position a div to bottom-right of button in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can set a div to top and left position of a button using following code:

```
var p = $("#tag-add");
var offset = p.offset();
$("#TagModal").offset({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left})
```

**Output:**

[image]

But I want to set the div to bottom right of button:

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: have you tried `float:right`?

Comment: use the link may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043102/how-to-get-right-offset-of-an-element-jquery][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var p = $("#tag-add");
var offset = p.offset();

var $modal = $("#TagModal");
$modal.offset({
  top: offset.top + p.outerHeight(),
  left: offset.left + p.outerWidth() - $modal.outerWidth()
});
```

(Subtract width of the modal from @PraveenKumar's example)

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/qn3ruu7j/) JSFiddle.

Comment: @JerryGoyal See update, you were setting `right` instead of `left`. Accutally, @PraveenKumar had changed it to `right` and i took the first template from his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$("#TagModal").offset({
  top: offset.top + p.outerHeight(),
  right: offset.left + p.outerWidth()
});
```

Comment: try before posting solution.. it's setting div to right

Comment: @JerryGoyal Post the code! I was just assuming and helping you. Please give a way to test out. Don't just ask us to set up stuff.

Comment: @JerryGoyal Can you please show us a working fiddle, so that I can prove this works? Or may be I should do some fiddling around.

Comment: @JerryGoyal A fiddle, please?

Comment: I'm new to UI developing but I'll create one if u want

Comment: @JerryGoyal It is **really needed**. Please do it.